# How to clear text fields using for loop in java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I created text fields in Java as following. When I click a "clear" button I want to clear all of these text fields at once.

```
private javax.swing.JTextField num1;
private javax.swing.JTextField num2;
private javax.swing.JTextField num3;
private javax.swing.JTextField num4;
private javax.swing.JTextField num5;
private javax.swing.JTextField num6;
private javax.swing.JTextField num7;
```

Now I want to know how to use a for loop to clear these all text fields like:

```
for(int i=1;1<7;i++){
   num[i].settext(null);
}
```

Comment: Create an array of JTextField instances and loop over that one.

Comment: 1) *"How can i do this???????"*  First fix that stuck '?' key!  2) Please use the correct spelling for words like 'you', 'your' & 'please'.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 3) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code like this:

```
private javax.swing.JTextField num1;
private javax.swing.JTextField num2;
private javax.swing.JTextField num3;
private javax.swing.JTextField num4;
private javax.swing.JTextField num5;
private javax.swing.JTextField num6;
private javax.swing.JTextField num7;
```

Is code that is crying out to be arranged and simplified by using collections or arrays. So if you use an array of JTextField or perhaps better an `ArrayList<JTextField>`. Then clearing them all is trivial.

```
public static final int FIELD_LIST_COUNT = 7;

private List<JTextField> fieldList = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

// in constructor
for (int i = 0; i < FIELD_LIST_COUNT; i++) {
  JTextField field = new JTextField();
  fieldList.add(field);
  fieldHolderJPanel.add(field); // some JPanel that holds the text fields
}

// clear method
public void clearFields() {
  for (JTextField field : fieldList) {
    field.setText("");
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm using this on netbeans(with using interface palette).So I cannot initialize textfields as an array when it creating.So then how?

Comment: @user2605013: then just put them in an ArrayList as I've already suggested. Note that you're far better off not using a code generation tool and instead creating your Swing code by hand til you understand Swing and Java.

Answer (score 7):

You can easily get the components inside the container by container.getComponents() method with consider some important things:

1. There may another container like JPanel.
2. There may another component like JLabel,JButton,....

Use this method:

```
public void clearTextFields (Container container){

  for(Component c : container.getComponents()){
   if(c instanceof JTextField){
     JTextField f = (JTextField) c;
     f.setText("");
 } 
  else if (c instanceof Container)
     clearTextFields((Container)c);
}
}
```

Call the method like this:

```
clearTextFields(this.getContentPane());
```

Comment: Why I would normally agree, what happens if the fields don't live in a single container?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Nothing happens, it's just the matter of design and separating the work area.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using this on netbeans(with using interface palette).So I cannot initialize textfields as an array when it creating.So then how?

Comment: @user2605013: I knew you're using *Netbeans* form, this method not need to create an array or List of `JTextFields`, it will do all the works only copy and paste it, but take my advice go and learn Swing by yourself, it's amazing, you'll find many interesting things ;).